# How to Run C and C++ Programs on VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As per my question, I want to compile & run **c/c++** program directly from Visual Studio Code (vscode).

so is there anything like live server (like HTML) when I save file it gets compiled and runs automatically...

Answer (score 0):

C++ support for Visual Studio Code is currently experimental. You may have look at [this extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) to accomplish what you ask.